# SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS) Dynamic Data Souce

Tags: reporting-services

I'm a very new user to SSRS. I learned the basic things and am able to make reports using VS 2008 and BIDS. But I can't move further. I want to use the dynamic data source. My issues are:

1. First the user should input four credentials: a)Server name b) database name c) user id 4) password. It will help to make the connection with database and make the data source. The credential should be stored in session or cookie.
2. Now the user will be able to see all the reports without giving the credential because he/she has already given them.

I made a dynamic data source but the credentials are asked for every time I open a report.

Any demo project or an articles will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like SSRS alone will not accomplish what you want. SSRS will not provide a good interface for end users to create new datasources, or change existing datasources. There are some potential workarounds that get some of the functionality you desire, such as a method to change servers found at:
http://blog.softartisans.com/2011/04/19/how-to-create-a-dynamic-reporting-services-shared-data-source-using-linked-servers/
(requires the ability to use linked servers.)

But to manage the user session or cookies, you will need more than SSRS. The easiest way to get at this will be with a .NET web site to manage the credentials. It might be able to use a ReportViewer control, or other method of accessing SSRS, such as URL access, to get reporting functionality.